# IF Field Exists in StandardSQL

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with these columns:

1. Apples
2. Bananas
3. Peaches - however, this column may or may not
   appear. The table is dropped and loaded every 5 hours and I need to
   be ready for situation where column "Peaches" is not available.

I have found couple similar questions here on StackOverflow but they were all using LegacySQL to solve the problem.

I was trying something like this:

SELECT *
FROM project.dataset.fruits

WHERE EXISTS(
  SELECT peaches
  FROM project.dataset.fruits
)

The code gives me that "peaches" is unknown name in case the "fruits" table does not currently have the column and the entire query fails.

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * FROM `project.dataset.fruits`
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM `project.dataset.fruits` t
  WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '[{,]"peaches":')
  LIMIT 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables#examples_3)

```sql
SELECT
 1
FROM
 `project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE
 table_name="fruits" AND column_name="peaches"
```